# Customizing Wordpress parent/child comments?

Tags: php, mysql, css, wordpress, themes

Here is what I'm trying to do, and I understand the way that wordpress has it already set up, but I rely heavily on being able to modify and basically change whatever I need too, and in core files as well. However, I am using multisite so changing the core file's is now not an option.

The image below is *somewhat* how I am wanting the final product to appear, but I noticed other than using wordpress's ul, ol & li styles, I need to be able to customize it more than what has been provided by that, just in case you are wondering why I'm taking the hard way.

Anyways, looking at the image below, where the white rectangle is, I'm wanting to be able to change the color and ultimately allow myself to change the formatting to whatever I want that is different for all user replies. I have no idea how I'd write it, but more than likely it'll have to be an if/else statement. Basically, it'll say:

If parent (depth 0) comment, display this formatting, else (depth of 1 or greater, which would be a child reply), this display it this. Any idea's?

Here is my [functions theme file](http://pastebin.com/59adVhcG) and my [comments theme file](http://pastebin.com/aQygZpgC). AND just in case, the [comment-template](http://pastebin.com/ectMLvSy) file under the wp-includes that says how to display and label the comments as parents/children.

[image: Sample]

I'd also like to point out, that I'm looking for help and suggestions, not criticism. If I knew the answer, I wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: How is this a MySQL question?

Comment: Because, the final code will more than likely include syntax references in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just colour you want to change, is there any reason you can't just use CSS? E.g. make a rule for li.depth-1, another for li.depth-2, etc.?

Comment: The thing is that the parent comment uses blockquote, and has it's own styling. The way they changed the comments, the child automatically adapts the parent coding, which includes the blockquote/css, and that is what I'm trying to change. I want it to stop using the blockquote/css at the child, but still allow all parents to use the blockquote, etc. Hopefully I am making sense. And it'll be more than just the color, I'm talking about total control over how the comments are displayed and be able to individually display aspects of it ultimately.

Comment: If there is anything else that can be done instead, I'd happily take it.

Answer (score 1):

Based off of what BDHorrigan said, I came up with the following:

```
blockquote {
  background: #292929;
  border-left: 7px solid #00D9FF;
color: #A3B808;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
}

blockquote:nth-child(1) {
    border-left: 7px solid #FFBE40;
}
```

This allowed every child reply to be the same because they would be all at a nth-child of 1. Thank you!